# Recursive call of interface implementation in rust language

Tags: interface, recursion, implementation, rust

How do I call recursively an interface I am implementing from the implementation of this interface?

I am doing the following thing:

```
import io::*;
import to_str::*;
enum some_enum {
  foo(~[some_enum]),
  bar
}

impl to_str for some_enum {
  fn to_str() -> str {
    alt self {
      bar { "bar" }
      foo(nest) { "foo" + nest.to_str() } // this line
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  println(foo(~[bar,bar,bar]).to_str());
}
```

And it fails at compile time with

```
user@note ~/soft/mine/rust $ rustc example.rs && ./example 
example.rs:13:32: 13:43 error: failed to find an implementation of interface core::to_str::to_str for some_enum
example.rs:13             foo(nest) { "foo" + nest.to_str() }
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Of course I can do an FP-like thing:

```
  foo(nest) { "foo" + nest.map(|x| { x.to_str() }).to_str() }
```

But why isn't the former case valid?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it can be solved with using `impl of` instead of `impl`.

`impl` without `of` acts like interface-less implementation, with no actual interface involved.

(confirming to http://dl.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial.html#interface-less-implementations )